# each(:as => :hash) works on localhost but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, foreach

In the Rails code on my computer, I'm writing a pure SQL query (I love SQL) and then parsing the results with:

```
friends.each(:as => :hash) do |row|
```

This all works fine, but when I try to push it to Heroku, I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)):
```

And it's complaining about the each loop.  Why could this be happening, is Heroku somehow behind, like with an older version of Ruby where you can't do this?  Or is it a MySQL vs. PostGreSQL (I'm using MySQL on my computer) thing?

Comment: The `#each` method does not take any arguments. Something funny must be happening if this works locally

Comment: `Mysql2::Result#each` takes parameters (see the [README](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#cascading-config)), but I'm not sure about the result returned by PostgreSQL adapter. It's much better to use the same DB for development and production, especially if you're writing a lot of SQL yourself and don't rely on the methods provided by `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: So when I get the result returned by `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`, what is the best way to parse it?  And how can I use MySQL on Heroku?  Or would it be easier to use PostGre on my computer?

Comment: Don't know. Check out Heroku and PostgreSQL adapter docs. In fact, hand-written SQL and `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` in a Rails app are bad signs.

Comment: Heroku only supports PostgreSQL. There are addons like **ClearDB** for MySQL on Heroku, but you should really consider moving to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Fair enough.  What's the quickest way to learn it?  I just want to learn how to jump from MySQL to PostGreSQL, not learn everything from scratch like a book would want me to do.

Comment: 1. Don't use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` ... 2. Use Postgres locally.

Answer (score -2):

You can use  other related syntax like

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows("select * from friends") which will return result as array of arrays.

or

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values("select * from friends") which will return array for first column values of all the selected records.